# stm32duino nucleo l432kc - No space left on device error

Tags: arduino, stm32, nucleo

I started writing an example code for a new board I purchased: STM32L432KCU6 32 PINS (Nucleo-32).
I'm using Arduino IDE to write the code and upload it to the STM32 board.
Unfortunately after a few uploads, I'm starting to get this error: `cp: /Volumes/NODE_L432KC/sketch_may29a.ino.bin: No space left on device`
followed by: `Failed uploading: uploading error: exit status 1`
So I already have here 2 STM32L432KCU6 boards that are not usable due to this error, and 1 left to go before I'll need to order a new board.

So obviously that's not optimal and I'm sure there's a way to fix it.
Started looking for an answer online, but it seems like it's impossible to do using only Arduino IDE. Tried using STM32CubeIDE and STM32CubeProgrammer to erase the board content and free some space, but those two require a device called ST-LINK which I don't currently own. I can purchase it, but I'm not sure if that's really the solution, and if I'll know how to work with it since I'm not too familiar with it (Only familiar with Arduino IDE tbh).

So I'm hoping someone here would save me with some super hero solution on how to avoid this `no-space` issue with stm32 board and stm32duino, or how to completly clear the content of the card and free some space, since it seems like Arduino IDE doesn't do so every time it uploads the new code to the board.

So just some background details on what I'm working with:

1. this is the board I'm working on: [https://www.amazon.com/dp/B077GFHLFS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B077GFHLFS)
2. I previously used esp32 but it drained my batteries pretty quickly so I wanted to try out the STM32 to hopefully get a longer battery life
3. Nothing is connected to the board pins, just USB that is connected to the laptop.
4. The current code I'm trying to upload is just for testing purposes, and it's a pretty blank Arduino example, like this one:

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
  Serial.println(STM32_CORE_VERSION);
  delay(3000);
}
```

As mentioned - after about 10 uploads it seems like I'm blocked from uploading new code, with the `no space` error mentioned above.

Would very much appreciate your kind help :)

Thanks!

Comment: Just to eliminate a possibility: did you check that you don’t have space issues on your own computer rather than on the board? What is the `NODE_L432KC` volume? Is that a USB stick? Is this really where you are intending things to be compiled on?

Comment: Hey, yes. `NODE_L432KC` is the right one. it was sending everything there when it was working as well.
And there is no space issue on my computer, so that can be eliminated :)

Comment: Possibly related: https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os/issues/2909 you may have to update the firmware of the boards?